# Where is the DNS Zone file for domains on a Plesk Centos server?

Tags: linux, centos, plesk

Been searching and searching without luck and i was hoping that someone could answer me here.

I have a Plesk server that has gone f*ck*. And now i need to retrieve the DNS as it can't be looked up via whois services for all the domains on the server. Such as MX records etc. Is here any file on Plesk/Centos servers that hosts those informations and do you know where it is ?.

Comment: No one knows anything about this ?

Answer (score 3):

All zones files are stored at /var/named/chroot/var/

Comment: There isn't any /var/named/.. any other idea where it can be ?.

Comment: Does bind even installed rpm -qa | grep bind  ?

Answer (score 2):

In Plesk 12.5, they are stored as autogenerated files by Plesk in:

> /var/named/run-root/var/

Within that folder you will see a separate file for each domain name which contains the DNS records.

See "Zone Files" at http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/Doc/ru-RU/online/plesk-linux-advanced-administration-guide/68760.htm#

Answer (score 0):

In Plesk 12.0.18, I found the zone files here:

```
/var/named/chroot/var
```